# Python Code to Copy lines from One CSV to Another and Add Column

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to use Python to copy lines from one csv file to another and add data to a new column in the process. The data is being copied correctly to the new file, but it's all being copied to the same line in the new file.

```
file = "C:/original_file.csv"
nf = "C:/file_updated.csv"

i = 0

with open(file, 'r') as origFile:
    with open(nf, 'w') as newFile:

        lineList = []
        for line in origFile:
            strippedLine = line.strip()
            lineList = strippedLine.split(',')

            lineList.append("C:/ATT" + str(i) + "_PHOTO 1.jpg")
            lineStr = str(lineList)
            lineStr = lineStr.replace("'", "")

            newFile.write(lineStr)
            print lineList
            i += 1

origFile.close()
newFile.close()
```

How can I make it so that each line from the first file copies to a separate line of the new file?

Comment: I think this is something that you could do effortlessly with pandas. Is there any reason you want to use only python?

Comment: The only reason was a lack of experience with pandas. But I will look into it.

Comment: If you want to solve it with pandas then I would suggest you to look at the solution of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58274401/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-merge-them-into-one-dataframe . Then there is a simple save functionality to csv.

Answer (score 2):

```
file = "C:/original_file.csv"
nf = "C:/file_updated.csv"

i = 0

with open(file, 'r') as origFile:
    with open(nf, 'w') as newFile:

        lineList = []
        for line in origFile:
            strippedLine = line.strip()
            lineList = strippedLine.split(',')

            lineList.append("C:/ATT" + str(i) + "_PHOTO 1.jpg")
            lineStr = str(lineList)
            lineStr = lineStr.replace("'", "")

            newFile.write(lineStr)
            newFile.write('\n') #Insert a new line
            print lineList
            i += 1

origFile.close()
newFile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

No need to install `pandas`, the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library is great for this!!

```
$ cat tmp.csv
first,second
third,fourth
```

```py
import csv

to_read = "./tmp.csv"
to_write = "./tmp2.csv"

with open(to_read, newline="") as to_read_fp, open(to_write, "w", newline="") as to_write_fp:
    reader = csv.reader(to_read_fp)
    writer = csv.writer(to_write_fp)

    for count, row in enumerate(reader):
        row.append(f"C:/ATT{count}_PHOTO 1.jpg")
        writer.writerow(row)
```

```
$ cat tmp2.csv
first,second,C:/ATT0_PHOTO 1.jpg
third,fourth,C:/ATT1_PHOTO 1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without any imports you could try something like this which adds a new column with the header `New Field`.

Of course it assumes the original CSV has a header row.

```py
file = "original_file.csv"
nf = "file_updated.csv"

with open(file, 'r') as origFile:
    data = [line.strip().split(',') for line in origFile.readlines()]

header = data[0]
data = data[1:]
header.append('New Field')       
data = [line + [f'C:/ATT{idx}_PHOTO 1.jpg'] for idx, line in enumerate(data)]
data = [','.join(line) for line in [header]+data]
        
with open(nf, 'w') as newFile:
    newFile.writelines('\n'.join(data))

"""
SAMPLE INPUT
Field1,Field2
Data1,Data2
Data3,Data4


SAMPLE OUTPUT
Field1,Field2,New Field
Data1,Data2,C:/ATT0_PHOTO 1.jpg
Data3,Data4,C:/ATT1_PHOTO 1.jpg
"""
```